# How to setup Google Cloud Compute Engine for Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, hosting

I have read a lot of articles and seen many YouTube videos but did not solved my problem. I want to know what are the process do we need to follow to purchase the host machine in **Google Cloud**? Is it free or do we need to pay something? Along with this if I want to deploy my **Spring Boot** project then what action do we need to perform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very good article written on [How to setup Google Cloud Compute Engine for Spring Boot project?](https://javaaltaf.blogspot.com/2020/01/setup-google-cloud-compute-engine.html) .

> According to this article you will have to do 2 activities.
>
> 1. Setup Billing Information
> 2. Setup the execution environment

***In 1st step***, you will have to signup/login using the Google Account by going https://console.cloud.google.com. Here it is mandatory to provide your **debit/card** details along with the **cvv** and you will have to pay **1 Rupee**. For verification purpose, you need to upload one of the governement id proof like **UID/Driving Licence/Passport** and your debit/credit photo. After submiting the form, it will take less than 4 hours to activate your cloud account. After activating your account you need to create your machine and based on the machine type you will be charged but make sure for 1 year Google will not charge you anything. Google will give you **$300** to spend on Google Cloud Platform products during your first **12 months**. For price details you can visit [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing).
[image]

***In the 2nd step***, you need to install your required softwares like Java, Git, Maven, PM2 etc. For ease of deployment you can use **PM2** which is a process manager for the JavaScript runtime Node.js. In your Spring Boot project root directory you need to create one configuration file `server.sh` file which contains `mvn spring-boot:run`. Make this file executable by using `chmod +x server.sh`. To start the server you just need to type `pm2 restart server`. After starting the server you can even check the logs by using `pm2 logs`.

> For better visibility & understanding I will recommend to read this complete [article](https://javaaltaf.blogspot.com/2020/01/setup-google-cloud-compute-engine.html).